# i make a flutter app but i need this app to connect to a custom dns server like 1.1.1.1 server

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dns

I make a market app in flutter and dart use firebase as backend. I need my app connect to  dns 1.1.1.1  programmatically before he is launched, because firebase block my country. I need any solution to do that programmatically. Is there a way or not, there is any files can i put dns server in it?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, these search results might be a better way to get started: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%5Bflutter%5D+programmatically+set+dns

Comment: No i search a lot but no one give me good answer i just want add dns server into my app